# Reaching /proc LACP bond infos as normal user?

Tags: sles, lacp

As a normal user I cannot see the

"details actor lacp pdu"

infos what are in:

/proc/net/bonding/bond0

Looks like only root can see that.

But how could a regular user see these LACP infos? Or only root can really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, only the *root* user, or more precisely a process with the CAP_NET_ADMIN capability has access to this information, as seen in sources for [`/proc`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/bonding/bond_procfs.c?h=v5.4#n141) and  for `/sys` [for](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/bonding/bond_sysfs.c?h=v5.4#n537) [various](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/bonding/bond_sysfs.c?h=v5.4#n557) [split](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/bonding/bond_sysfs.c?h=v5.4#n577) [fi](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/bonding/bond_sysfs.c?h=v5.4#n686)[les](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/bonding/bond_sysfs.c?h=v5.4#n715).

> ```
>   if (capable(CAP_NET_ADMIN)) {
> ```

> ```
>   if (BOND_MODE(bond) == BOND_MODE_8023AD && capable(CAP_NET_ADMIN)) {
> ```

This might perhaps be for reasons invoked in the [`bonding.txt`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt?h=v5.4#n1671) documentation:

> 3.7 Configuring LACP for 802.3ad mode in a more secure way
>
> ---
>
> When using 802.3ad bonding mode, the Actor (host) and Partner (switch)
> exchange LACPDUs.  These LACPDUs cannot be sniffed, because they are
> destined to link local mac addresses (which switches/bridges are not
> supposed to forward).  However, most of the values are easily
> predictable or are simply the machine's MAC address (which is
> trivially known to all other hosts in the same L2). **This implies that
> other machines in the L2 domain can spoof LACPDU packets from other
> hosts to the switch and potentially cause mayhem by joining (from the
> point of view of the switch) another machine's aggregate, thus
> receiving a portion of that hosts incoming traffic and / or spoofing
> traffic from that machine themselves** (potentially even successfully
> terminating some portion of flows). Though this is not a likely
> scenario, one could avoid this possibility by simply configuring few
> bonding parameters:

Whatever the steps described later to prevent this, this wouldn't help if a non-privileged user on this system could exfiltrate the information to an hostile system in the same LAN.

So you probably need to have an helper process with the correct access rights. You could simply create a shell script that retrieve the informations and that can be called as root with sudo, or you can create a binary executable with appropriate access and stick the CAP_NET_ADMIN capability to it:

```
chown root:allowedgroup /path/to/helper-binary
chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=r /path/to/helper-binary
setcap cap_net_admin+ep /path/to/helper-binary
usermod -aG allowedgroup specialuser
```

Also you should consider switching to using entries in `/sys/class/net/INTERFACE/bonding/` because they are more easily parsable than from `/proc/net/bonding/` (and they also provide an [alternate method to (re)configure bonding](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt?h=v5.4#n1465), along with `/sys/class/net/bonding_masters` ).

Comment: note: as a test, even this would work: `cp -p /bin/cat /path/to/helper-binary`